# Error in starting the jboss server

Tags: jboss7.x

I installed Jboss server in windows xp . When I try to execute "run.bat" I got an error as

" To start JBoss Application Server please see C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Fin al\bin..\README.txt"

Before executing "run.bat" I set the environment variable 
JBOSS_HOME =  C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final;

After getting an error I saw that "readme.txt", it says that "This jar should be used
with standalone clients only, not with deployments are that deployed to an AS7 instance." 
What is the problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `run.bat`. Use either `%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\standanlone.bat` or `%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\domain.bat`. I would start with standalone as that's probably the one you want. Domain is for running multiple instances and wanting one management interface to interact with each server.